# Setting a default TEXT value to a combobox bound to a numeric value

Tags: ms-access

Seemingly trivial question but I can't seem to get this working no matter what I try.

A typical use case is when I want the default text to describe the combobox field, e.g. "Select an item", but the combobox is referencing a table, bound to the `ID` column but displaying the `name` of the item.

Another case is when I have a default value I am not sure won't be null and would like to display something in case it is null.

I can set the value of the combobox to a text value, but nothing shows up. Referencing the value does give me back the text value I originally set it to, so it is purely a display issue.

Anyone know how I might resolve this?

Comment: how about looping for each item till find the value ?

Comment: Should this field show the default value as soon as it loads?  Or will it appear after the field updates somehow?

Comment: @TKEyi60 as soon as the field loads generally

Comment: @matzone I'm not quite sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily the "cleanest" solution but you can add a record on your table that is bound and set that as your default value

e.g.

```
ID   Value
--   -----
 1   "Select Item"
 2   "Item 1"
 3   "Item 2"
```

Comment: I considered this, but in all querys/reports or anything referencing the table, I then have to make sure I ignore that particular ID.